# Excel: Change the value of a selected value from a validation list using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have a column with a data validation list in each cell.

Here is my list:

```
ND - No Delivery
SD - Short Delivery
OD - Over Delivery
Other
```

What I want to try and achieve here is if the user selects the value from the data validation list, then the cell changes to one of the following:

```
ND - No Delivery = ND

SD - Short Delivery = SD

OD - Over Delivery = OD

Other = Other
```

So my cells end up potentially looking something like this:

```
ND
SD
OD
Other
```

So if the user selects No Delivery, then the value in the cell is set to 'ND', and so on.

The only exception here would be other, which should still be set to other in the cell.

Here is a sample code to put it in to context:

```
   If .Range("B1").Value = "ND - No Dleivery" Then
      .Range("B1").Value = "ND"
   End If
```

My validation for the cell should really only allow either 'ND', 'SD', 'OD' or 'Other' to be entered - but the list should contain:

```
ND - No Delivery
SD - Short Delivery
OD - Over Delivery
Other
```

Please can someone show me the best way to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you'd then loose the validation functionality in that cell: is that ok?  BTW you may want to take your time and give feedback to answers to many  previous questions of yours

Comment: Could i have the list like the above but change the cell validation to ND, SD, OD etc? @user3598756

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there any visual and explain more, would be great if you can provide some sample?

On the selected cell that you want to reflect the selected option.

```
=IFERROR(IF(A2="No Delivery";"ND";IF(A2="Short 
         Delivery";"SD";IF(A2="Over Delivery";"OD")));"Other")
```

Tell me if this is the one you need.

Thanks

[Sample- is it like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eadx5.png)

[Excel Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Spjw.png)

Comment: how would i create this using vba?

Comment: Hi, I did not create this using VBA. Is it a requirement to be in VBA? Does it have to be on the same cell for the content to grab the value example. "ND"?